# How to add a model equation to a rapidminer Apply Model plot?

Tags: rapidminer

Let's suppose you run a linear regression.

The model equation in Linear Regression process and the prediction plot in Apply Model process end up in different result windows.

Is it possible to annotate the Apply Model plot (showing data and linear regression fit/prediction) with the linear regression model equation?  (the way Excel does hum hum!)

If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on no response on such a simple question and my investigations, I conclude it is not possible in RapidMiner 5 (at least not with a fairly straightforward mechanism) to show in the "Apply Model" scatter plot the same linear regression model equation as shown in "Text View".

Answer (score 0):

You can plot both the prediction and the original label in the same plot with the Scatter (Multiple) Plot.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to plot the prediction and training data on the same graph.  The question is how to show the model equation on the graph?  For instance, add to the plot something like: y = 2.3 * x + 5.6 where 2.3 and 5.6 are the coefficients from the Linear Regression -- that is the content of Linear Regression Text View.